# How-to preg_match/preg_match_all with constant or var in regex?

Tags: php, preg-match, constants, preg-match-all

I have the following pattern:

```
preg_match( "/^(.*?\/wp-content\/)([^\?]+)(.*)$/", $src, $src_bits );
```

Now I want to set `wp-content` to a constant named `WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME` that holds the folder name. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply by using PHP:

```
preg_match( "/^(.*?\/" . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME . "\/)([^\?]+)(.*)$/", $src, $src_bits );
```